# Eclipse doesn't recognise Play framework

Tags: eclipse, playframework, sbteclipse

I am trying to integrate Hello world play project for the first time with Eclipse using java. Eclipse can't resolve views.html.index. Do I need to install anything to have Play framework support in Eclipse?

I followed page https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/IDE for Eclipse. The picture in documentation doesn't show any error for scala class and I would expect same for java but I am getting errors. Also in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmhHwX_fTFo&feature=youtu.be&t=489) they struggled with it but at the end it worked for them.

[image]

I am using: macOS, java 11.0.3, STS4 (Spring Tool Suite 4) that uses Eclipse 4.11.0, java correctly set in STS.

Thank you

Comment: Where is it? It's not in the image if I'm looking at it right.

Comment: @nitind, the error is shown when I hover the icon with the red cross and says 'views.html.index cannot be resolved to a type'.

Comment: I understand that. I meant, where is *views.html.index*? Why *would* it be found--it's not seen here.

Comment: I am not sure how it is implemented behind the scene but it should : https://youtu.be/hmhHwX_fTFo?t=489

Comment: try to clean your project your in eclipse